# Event Bubbling jQuery + Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just developed a simple page, using the standard jQuery tabs

[jQuery Tabs Link](http://stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs/)

I've include the jQuery history/remote plugin to allow bookmarking and back navigation.

There are some JavaScript elements within the tabs themselves, such as lightbox, which is called on page load. The history/remote plugin seems to be affecting any javascript within the tabs, as no JS within will work anymore.

Could anyone give me a little insight as to how I may resolve this issue? Possibly using event bubbling...

Many Thanks,
M

Comment: Are you loading the tabs onShow using AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `onShow` callback and initialize lightbox and other scripts after the tab is shown.